# No Reverse Match - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/(?P[^/]+)$'] [18/Apr/2020 14:05:02] "GET /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 157543 <--- this is the error message I am getting in terminal when I try to go onto the checkout page.

view.html

```
{% for item in cart.products.all %}

<tr><td> {{ item }} </td><td>{{item.price}}</td>

<td><a href='{% url "update_cart" item.slug %}'> Remove</a></td></tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>

<br/>

<a href='{% url "checkout" %}'>Checkout</a>

{% endif %}
</div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

views.py for orders

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.

from carts.models import Cart

def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    except:
        the_id = None
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("fuisce-home"))


    context = {}
    template = "fuisce/home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from carts import views as cart_views
from orders import views as order_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='fuisce-home'),
    path('subscription/', views.subscription, name='fuisce-subscription'),
    path('oneoff/', views.oneoff, name='fuisce-oneoff'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='fuisce-about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='fuisce-contact'),
    path('cart/', cart_views.view, name='cart'),
    path('cart/<slug>', cart_views.update_cart, name='update_cart'),
    path('checkout/', order_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
]
```

the problem seems to arise when i move the HttpResponse from just below def checkout, to below cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id). (change in code attached below). anyone know how to let it accept this change?

```
def checkout(request):
    ***return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("fuisce-home"))***
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
except:
            the_id = None

def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    except:
        the_id = None
        ***return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("fuisce-home"))***
```

views.py for cart

```
def update_cart(request, slug):
    request.session.set_expiry(120000)
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass

    if not product in cart.products.all():
        cart.products.add(product)
    else:
        cart.products.remove(product)

    new_total = 0.00
    for item in cart.products.all():
        new_total += float(item.price)

    request.session['items_total'] = cart.products.count()
    cart.total = new_total
    cart.save()

    return redirect('cart')
```

models.py - product

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    desc = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)    
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='fuisce/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown by  [reverse()](http://reverse)

1. It accepts viewname as the argument.
2. The viewnames can be found from the urlpatterns defined.

I see there is no viewname `fuisce-home` defined in urlpatterns. Thats why the error is coming.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i do have fuisce-home in my urls, I just cut it out as i thought i was showing too much code. i have edited the main post to include it now

Comment: thanks for the idea but unfortunately that solution didn't work for me either. --------- django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart\\/(?P<slug>[^/]+)$'] -------- i just can't seem to get rid of this error. From my understanding the problem seems to be originating in the views.py file

Comment: Do you have value for item.slug ? Can you check that? The " update-cart"  reverse URL expects the argument.

Comment: Yes i believe so. i edited in my models.py and views.py that includes the value for item.slug. Maybe there is an issue here that I am missing?